How can I convert my python ( .py) file into an executable (.exe) file using pyinstaller?
I am working on a PySide6 application that consists of multiple Python files and folders. When I run the project using python main.py, everything works perfectly. However, I’m struggling to convert it into a standalone .exe file that includes all the necessary files and assets.
Here is the structure of my project:
MyProject/  # A folder
├── main.py  # Entry point of the application
├── models.py  # A file
├── staff.db # A file
├── utils.py  # A file
├── photos/  # Contains image resources
├── views/ # A folder
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main_app.py  # Contains the MainApp class used in main.py
│   ├── admin_views/ # A folder
│   │   ├── __init__.py # A file
│   │   ├── admin_file1.py # A file
│   │   ├── admin_file2.py # A file
│   │   ├── ...  # Other files in admin_views
│   ├── ...  # Other Python files related to the views

When I attempt to open the generated .exe, I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'

The application starts with main.py, which imports the MainApp class from views/main_app.py. This file interacts with other files and resources within the views folder and other parts of the project.
I used the following PyInstaller command to convert my main.py file into an executable:
pyinstaller --name "MyProject" --onefile --windowed --icon=resources/icon.ico main.py

After running the .exe, I get an error message box that says:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'views'

This suggests that PyInstaller is not including the views folder (or other assets) in the final build.
Observations

The application works perfectly when I run it using python main.py.

I suspect PyInstaller is not bundling all the files, folders, and dependencies in my project.

The views folder contains multiple Python files, and main.py relies on the MainApp class from views/main_app.py.

There’s also an admin_views folder inside views, containing additional modules that are required.


Questions

How do I ensure PyInstaller includes all the files, folders, and assets in my project during the conversion process?

Is there a specific PyInstaller configuration or approach for multi-file projects like mine?

Should I be using --onefile, or is there a better approach to handle this kind of project?


Any guidance or solutions to successfully bundle my entire project into an .exe would be greatly appreciated!

I used the following PyInstaller command to generate the executable:
pyinstaller --name "MyProject" --onefile --windowed --icon=resources/icon.ico main.py

After running the .exe, I encountered the error mentioned above.
Additionally, I tried the following to resolve the issue:

Added __init__.py files to the relevant folders to make them proper Python modules.

Checked if PyInstaller automatically includes the folders like views and admin_views.

Ran PyInstaller with the --paths flag to explicitly include the views folder


What I Am Expecting
I want to create a standalone .exe file that includes all the files and dependencies in my project, such that the application behaves the same way as it does when I run python main.py. Specifically:

The .exe should find and use the views and admin_views modules without errors.

All assets, like the database (staff.db) and resources (photos folder), should be packaged within the executable.



You should give the path where your modules located through --paths ; If still not recognized, use --hiddenimport=views

For data bundle https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/phvonv/pyinstaller_data_files_with_onefile_bundled/

# MyProject.spec

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=['.'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('photos', 'photos'), ('staff.db', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='MyProject',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    icon='resources/icon.ico',
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='MyProject',
)


While code-only answers are not officially frowned upon, they are commonly discouraged, especially if the contents of the code doesn't clarify what actually makes the code relevant and reliable. Please take your time and [edit] your post in order to provide at least a minimal explanation of why that spec file works.
